# Can not apply filter on @hybrid_property in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

The code is simple as:

```
Class A(Base):
    status = Columns(Integer)

    @hybrid_property
    def is_ok(self):
        return self.status > 0
```

But

```
session.query(A).filter(A.is_ok).all()
```

will raise Exception: `TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined`.

I've tried `print result[0].is_ok, type(result[0].is_ok)`. It was `True <type 'bool'>`.

So how can I filter based on a `hybrid_property`

---

**My Answer**

With the help from @van, I kind of knowing how.

The arg [`filter(*criterion)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) takes should be a [SQL expression object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html). I used to think that it takes a boolean as arg, **BUT NO!**

> The criterion is any SQL expression object applicable to the WHERE clause of a select. String expressions are coerced into SQL expression constructs via the text() construct.

Code tells:

```
# wrong code:
@is_ok.expression
def is_ok(self):
    return self.status > 30 and self.status < 90

# correct code:
from sqlalchemy.sql import and_
@is_ok.expression
def is_ok(self):
    return and_(self.status > 30, self.status < 90).label('is_ok')
```

Comment: Great. Add your solution as an answer and accept it for a good knowledge base.

Comment: I think your `.expression` is the key. :)

Comment: Careful of the typo: "@is_ok.expressoin"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a custom expression. Below uses `CASE` statement, but you could use `IF` as well if you db supports it:

```
@is_ok.expression
def is_ok(cls):
    return case([(cls.status > 0, True)], else_=False).label("is_ok")
```

---

*See [`Defining Expression Behavior Distinct from Attribute Behavior`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior) documentation for more info.*

Comment: If I'm using `self.status >= 30`, it goes well. But if I'm using `self.status >= 30 and self.status < 90`, it raises. What's the difference?

Comment: But what if the data is on the instance level? Like my hybrid property is using another hybrid property to define its value. Now going to class level returns all of that hybrid property for me instead of the hybrid properties of independent instances (like with `self`).

Comment: @MattSom, you need both: the instance property and the expression. Only in simple cases can sqlalchemy figure out the expression without explicit definition, but for anything a bit more complex (like your recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67489770/99594) you will need to have a well defined expression corresponding to the property definition. So two different "implementations".

Comment: So in that case I have to reimplement the used and the 'main' hybrid property logic again? Like my first HP used a group by and that was used in the second. Now for my expression in the second HP I need to define a grouped entity again for the first HP so I can rebuild my logic? This would mean if my hybrid properties use a tons of other hybrid properties, the expression for the last one's is always redoing the work. Or I should just create a class level expression for every HP and use them in the same way?

Comment: I might have mis-understood your original question here. No, you do not need to re-implement all from scratch, you can absolutely re-use your implementations and sqlalchemy will compose those properly.