# Calculated boolean column showing if column is newest

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, subquery, calculated-columns

I have a table with a structure that more or less (I've simplified it for the question) looks like the following:

| id (P.K.) | creation_ts | some_field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-19 | foo |
| 2 | 2021-08-18 | foo |
| 3 | 2021-08-17 | foo |
| 4 | NULL | bar |
| 5 | 2021-01-01 | bar |
| 6 | 2021-01-02 | bar |

And I'm trying build a query to show a calculated column that per each row with the same value for `"some_field"` (erm... grouped by the value of `"some_field"` if you may?) would add an extra column `is_newest` showing which row is the newest.

| id (P.K.) | creation_ts | some_field | is_newest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-19 | foo | TRUE |
| 2 | 2021-08-18 | foo | FALSE |
| 3 | 2021-08-17 | foo | FALSE |
| 4 | NULL | bar | FALSE |
| 5 | 2021-01-01 | bar | FALSE |
| 6 | 2021-01-02 | bar | TRUE |

The intention of this is to create a SqlAlchemy [Hybrid property](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior) so we could quickly query things like *"get me the newest record `WHERE some_field = 'foo'`"*

I imagine this must be some kind of `CASE` statement (at least that's what I gather from [this other S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67556495/289011), which looks pretty promising) but the best thing I can come with is something like:

```py
    @is_newest.expression
    def is_newest(cls):
        subq = sa.sql.exists().where(
            sa.and_(
                cls.id != cls.id,
                cls.some_field == cls.some_field,
                # Dirty trick: If there aren't newer records than this one,
                # then this must be the newest
                cls.creation_ts > cls.creation_ts,
            )
        )
        return sa.case([(subq, False)], else_=True).label("is_newest")
```

but no: that seems pretty wrong to me (and it isn't working, since some unit tests are failing), because it produces a query like...

```sql
SELECT table.id, table.creation_ts, table.some_field
 FROM table WHERE 
  CASE WHEN (EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
       table.id != table.id 
       AND table.some_field = table.some_field
       AND table.creation_ts > table.creation_ts)
    ) THEN False 
    ELSE True END IS true 
AND table.some_field = 'foo'
```

... which doesn't look right. Though to be honest, I'm not very sure what would *"look right"* (I'm quite a newbie with Postgres)

Any hint would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this window function query as native:

```sql
select the_table.*, 
 coalesce(creation_ts = max(creation_ts) over (partition by some_field), false) is_newest
from the_table;
```

or (better) make a view out of it and then use the view instead of the table.
Result:

```
id|creation_ts|some_field|is_newest|
--+-----------+----------+---------+
 1|2021-08-19 |foo       |true     |
 2|2021-08-18 |foo       |false    |
 3|2021-08-17 |foo       |false    |
 4|           |bar       |false    |
 5|2021-01-01 |bar       |false    |
 6|2021-01-02 |bar       |true     |
```

**Edit**
Added `coalesce` to `is_newest` expression.